# Derive secret key from a longer secret key

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, digital-signature, hmac

I use a user provided 32 byte secret key to sign some data using HMAC-256. I also want my application to encrypt data using AES-192. Should I ask the user for another secret key (this time 16 bytes in size) or is there a secure way to derive a 16 byte strong secret key from the other 32 byte key? Second method would make the application configuration a bit easier. Any guidelines or tips? Or is this approach complete nonsense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tool for this is an [HKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF). This is a very good way to derive multiple keys from the same initial keying material. I would recommend that you use HKDF to derive both keys from the initial 32-byte secret, rather than deriving the AES key directly from the HMAC key. Typically you would stretch your 32 bytes IKM to 48 bytes and then split it into your two keys.

This is assuming that the initial 32 byte keying material is random. If it isn't, you should use PBKDF2 (or another password stretcher like scrypt or bcrypt) to stretch your keying material to 48 bytes and then split it into your two keys. HKDF is too fast of an algorithm to use with human-created passwords.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, HKDF is exactly what I was searching for. I think I will force users to set up a strong application global secret and derive the keys for my various components from this one.